# Where did this method for solving the following SDE go wrong?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

For the following Stochastic Differential Equation:
\begin{align*}
dX_1&=k_aX_1 dt + \sigma_1X_1 dW \\
dX_2&=(k_bX_2- k_aX_1)dt + (\sigma_2X_2 - \sigma_1X_1)dW \\
X_1(0&)=C, \quad X_2(0)=D.
 \end{align*}

I used the transformation  $Y= \left[\begin{array}{l}1&0\\1&1\end{array}\right] X  $ ,  where I define $X=[X_1,X_2]^T$.

The transformed problem becomes:
\begin{align*}
dY_1&=k_aY_1 dt + \sigma_1Y_1 dW \\
dY_2&=k_b(Y_2-Y_1)dt + \sigma_2(Y_2-Y_1) dW \\
Y_1(0&)=C, \quad Y_2(0)=C+D,
 \end{align*} by Ito's formula.

Solving the transformed problem we get:
\begin{align*} &Y_1=Ce^{\sigma_1W(t)+\left(K_a -\frac{\sigma_1^2}{2}\right)t} ,&Y_2=(C+D)e^{\sigma_2W(t)+\left(K_b -\frac{\sigma_2^2}{2}\right)t} \end{align*}

Transforming back we get:
\begin{align*} &X_1=Y_1, &X_2=Y_2 - Y_1.\end{align*}

This doesn't look like it should be correct, although I haven't gained an intuition for this yet.

I attempted to evaluate if this solution was correct by comparing this solution to one produced by an SDE solver on both MATLAB and Julia but cannot draw conclusive results.

**Question: Where does the solution go wrong? What are some alternative methods to check a SDE has been solved correctly?**

Comment: Your final formulas for $X_i$ will be of the form $f_i(W,t)$ for some nice functions $f_i$. Why not apply Ito's formula to this and check that what you get is the original SDE?

Comment: I think you made a small mistake with the change of variable:

$$dY_2 = d(X_1+X_2) = k_bX_2dt + \sigma_bX_2dW = k_b(Y_2-Y_1)dt + \sigma_b(Y_2-Y_1)dW.$$

Comment: You can not ignore $Y_1$ in the solution of the second $Y$ equation, you solved it as if it did not exists

Comment: Where is the stochastic PDE in this question?